Bash completion for a program in a specific directory
If I have a program located in /a/prog and /a is not in PATH, is it possible to specify a bash completion for running ./prog in /a so that it doesn't affect any other program named prog located anywhere else?
To clarify, here's an example:
_complete_prog() {
    [ "$COMP_CWORD" == 1 ] && \
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "aaa bbb" "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
}
complete -F _complete_prog ./prog

This will make only the first argument of ./prog tab complete as follows
$ ./prog <TAB><TAB>
aaa bbb


I don't want this completion to apply for ./prog if that's a different file, e.g. /b/prog.

I want for the same completion to apply for /a/prog and ././prog or any other path that leads to the same file.



[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Bash completions are programmable. This is a bash programming question.

Most customization of bash completion doesn't require programming, it's just using built-in pattern matching options. If this turns out to be more complicated, then feel free to reopen this question.

It's not really clear to me what you're asking for.  Do you want your shell to respond to ./pr<tab> by expanding to ./prog?  By default, bash already does that (if prog has the executable bit set).   Maybe you just need to chmod +x /a/prog to get the behavior you want.

Just like this:
$ complete -W 'aaa bbb'    foo
$ complete -W 'ccc ddd'  ./foo
$ complete -W 'eee fff' /a/foo

$ foo <TAB><TAB>
aaa  bbb

$ ./foo <TAB><TAB>
ccc  ddd

$ /a/foo <TAB><TAB>
eee  fff

As we can see, Bash completion can distinguish between foo and ./foo.

The problem is that ./foo and /a/foo have to be specified separately. Is there a way to have the same completion for the program file regardless of what path is used to run it? For example, so that ./foo and ././foo behave the same.

i dont think that's possible. for example, with compete -d cd, bash even cannot handle "cd" <TAB><TAB>.
